# how to make client to check if the server is done with read operation from pipe before writing data into pipe in c++

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, named-pipes

I need my client to first check if server is reading data from pipe, if yes then wait till server is done else write data into pipe. If I don't use sleep command in my sample client program then Server doesn't read message properly.I found the reason of this issue from the documentation it says:

> This buffer must remain valid for the duration of the read operation. The caller must not use this buffer until the read operation is completed.

But it doesn't specify how to block client until the read operation is complete.

Server Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead;


hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
                        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
                        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                        1,
                        1024 * 16,
                        1024 * 16,
                        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                        NULL);
while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
    {
        while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
            /* add terminating zero */
            buffer[dwRead] = '\0';

            /* do something with data in buffer */
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
}

return 0;
```

}

Client Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;
void fun()
{
     HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;


    hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"), 
                       GENERIC_WRITE, 
                       0,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       0,
                       NULL);
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(hPipe,
                  "Hello Pipe",
                  11,   // = length of string + terminating '\0' !!!
                  &dwWritten,
                  NULL);

        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }

}
int main(void)
{
   int a = 5;
   cout<<a;
   for(int i = 0; i<a; i++)
   {
    fun();
    Sleep(2000);
   }

    return (0);
}
```

This is just a sample program, actually my client is a very big application it has many functions and I don't want to make any major changes in it. Whenever a particular function gets triggered it should pass data to server. The type of data is a structure. After receiving data in server I want to write that data into text file (After converting it into json format).

So how can I make my client to check if the server is done reading data from pipe before writing data into pipe? Client should not wait forever for the server as it will affect my client application. It should wait for a specified time interval. Also to pass structure which pipe mode should I use BYTE MODE or MESSAGE MODE?

Comment: *how to block client until the read operation is complete* - because you use synchronous handles this will be done auto by system. *how to check..* you not need check this. and at all this is impossible. your task - open file and write data to it. if you want not block - use asynchronous handles

Comment: My server is not reading data properly if I dont use sleep(). If its done automatically then why I'm not getting the correct output?

Comment: because some errors in your code. of course not need any `Sleep`

Comment: also your server logic is incorrect - `ConnectNamedPipe` can return false with error `ERROR_NO_DATA` but data actual exist in pipe. you can call `ReadFile` in this case too. can be and `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` error for call `ConnectNamedPipe` - again - this is ok code and need `ReadFile` after this

Comment: I'm new to pipes concept so, Can you please write the modified client and server code in the answer?

Comment: If I dont use ConnectNamedPipe then how will I keep my server alive. In my case I need one continuous server that will read data whenever client connects.

Comment: you wrong use `ConnectNamedPipe`. more exactly you wrong interpret it result. even if it return false, it can not fail. you must check `GetLastError` after this call - `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` and `ERROR_NO_DATA` - is ok

Answer (score 1):

main error in next line of server code

```
if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)
```

here we assume that if [`ConnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146(v=vs.85).aspx) return `FALSE` it fail. but this is not true even for synchronous pipe handle:

> Otherwise, `ConnectNamedPipe` returns zero, and `GetLastError` returns
>   `ERROR_NO_DATA` if the previous client has closed its handle or
>   `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` if it has not closed its handle.

client can connect (call `CreateFile`) **after** server call `CreateNamedPipeW` but **before** call `ConnectNamedPipe`. exactly in this case driver(*npfs*) can return 2 status on `FSCTL_PIPE_LISTEN` (`ConnectNamedPipe`) request:

1. `STATUS_PIPE_CONNECTED` (translated to `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` ) if
   client already connect (before `FSCTL_PIPE_LISTEN`) and yet not
   close own handle)
2. `STATUS_PIPE_CLOSING` (translated to `ERROR_NO_DATA`) client has
   closed its handle. but he can call `WriteFile` before this and some data in pipe actually exist.

also use `NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT` in call `CreateNamedPipeW` - here must be actual timeout. this constant used in call [`WaitNamedPipeW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-waitnamedpipea) instead.

the synchronous pipe client/server can be tested by next code. (of course much better use asynchronous i/o)

```
ULONG WINAPI ct(void* name)
{
    if (WaitNamedPipeW((PCWSTR)name, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT))
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"client delay #1", 0);// for debug

        HANDLE hPipe = CreateFileW((PCWSTR)name, 
            GENERIC_WRITE, 
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);

        if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            static WCHAR str[] = L"Hello Pipe";

            DWORD dwWritten;

            WriteFile(hPipe, str,
                sizeof(str),
                &dwWritten,
                NULL);

            MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"client delay #2", 0);// for debug

            CloseHandle(hPipe);
        }
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

void sc()
{
    char buffer[1024];

    static WCHAR name[] = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe";

    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipeW(name,
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        1024 * 16,
        1024 * 16,
        INFINITE,
        NULL);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int n = 2;
        do
        {
            CloseHandle(CreateThread(0, 0, ct, name, 0, 0));
            MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"Server delay", 0);// for debug

            switch (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())
            {
            case NOERROR:
            case ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED: // STATUS_PIPE_CONNECTED
            case ERROR_NO_DATA: // STATUS_PIPE_CLOSING

                DWORD dwRead;
                while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwRead, NULL))
                {
                    /* do something with data in buffer */
                    printf("%.*S", dwRead, buffer);
                }

                DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
                break;
            }
        } while (--n);

        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }
}
```