# Error while writing into pipe in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ipc, named-pipes

I'm trying to implement basic named pipe implementation.
In my client code if I call `fun()` only one time then my program runs completely fine.
But when I call `fun()` more than one time then it fails alternatively(e.g. if I call `fun()` 3 times, first call will be successful, second call will fail and third call runs fine.
When the call fails in `GetLastError()` I get `231` as output on my screen.
If I use `Sleep()` after every `fun()` call in client then my program runs fine for every `fun()` call.
If I use `Sleep()` in my server program then it reads from from buffer only one time and all the calls (after the first call) to `fun()` fail in client side.

**Server Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
  HANDLE hPipe;
  char buffer[1024];
  DWORD dwRead;

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
            PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,  // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
            1,
            1024 * 16,
            1024 * 16,
            INFINITE,
            NULL);
    while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        switch (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())
        {
            case NOERROR:
            case ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED: // STATUS_PIPE_CONNECTED
            case ERROR_NO_DATA: // STATUS_PIPE_CLOSING

                while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, &dwRead, NULL))
                {
                     // do something with data in buffer 
                     //Sleep(2000);
                     buffer[dwRead] = '\0';
                printf("%s", buffer);                        
                }
                DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);

                break;
        }
    //CloseHandle(hPipe);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;


void fun()
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;

    hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"), 
                    GENERIC_WRITE, 
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    0,
                    NULL);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
        WriteFile(hPipe,
            "Hello Pipe\n",
            12,  // = length of string + '\0'
            &dwWritten,
            NULL);

        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }
    else
  {
        cout<<"****";
        cout<<GetLastError();
        cout<<"****";
    }
}

int main(void)
{     
    fun(); //Success
    //Sleep(2000);
    fun(); //failure
    //Sleep(2000);
    fun(); //Success
    //Sleep(2000);
    fun(); //failure
    //Sleep(2000);
    fun(); //Success    

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named Pipe CreateFile() returns INVALID\_HANDLE\_VALUE, and GetLastError() returns ERROR\_PIPE\_BUSY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529193/named-pipe-createfile-returns-invalid-handle-value-and-getlasterror-returns)

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: why you drop `WaitNamedPipe` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134527/6401656) ?

Comment: Try to set parameter `nMaxInstances` of `CreateNamedPipe()` to `PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES`.

Comment: Also your `while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` should be `if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` as `hPipe` never changes inside of the loop. You will never break out of the loop.